# Last.fm scrobbling for radio

Tags: rhythmbox

In windows, the last.fm plugin for foobar can scrobble music from internet radio. Is there any equivalent software in Ubuntu that support it? I have tried rhythmbox but it cannot do it.

I'm not asking about how to install last.fm plugin because I can use the scrobbling plugin in rhythmbox for any audio files in my computer (It scrobbles just fine). But it failed to scrobble when I try to listen to the internet radio. Hope that explanation clears enough.

Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope it clears any confusion.

Comment: Radio play will not be scrobbled. I have the last.fm scrobbler working with banshee, audacious, and rhythmbox. Some of the last.fm  functionality is limited (like radio). This is the case in 12.04, 14.04, and 16.04. Radio scrobbling will not work in my experience.

Comment: In my opinion, this is NOT a duplicate question.

Comment: This really isn't a duplicate question.  Anyway - I've found that Clementine (https://www.clementine-player.org/) does stream tracks listened to via internet radio streams to last.fm.